# Replace multiple values using another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, replace, multiple-columns

I want to replace different values in different columns using another data frame

df1

```
v1   v2 v3  v4
RDA  NA ILL NA
OPCS NA NA  NA
OJK  BR ILL PE
```

df2

```
v1  v2  v3  v5
RDA COL ILL P3
OPCS BR ILL P2
```

and I would like the output data frame to look like this:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4 v5
RDA COL ILL NA P3
OPCS BR ILL NA P2
OJK  BR ILL PE NA
```

I have tried using inner_join, but don't work and looks like this

```
v1  v2.x v2.y v3.x v3.y v4 v5
RDA NA   COL  ILL  NA    NA P3
OPCS NA  BR   NA   ILL   NA P2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

new <- setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))
merge_vars <- "v1"

rows_patch(df1, select(df2, -all_of(new)), by = merge_vars) |>
  left_join(select(df2, all_of(c(merge_vars, new))), by = merge_vars)
```

`?rows_patch` only overwrites `NA` values. If you want to update any values you can use `rows_update`. Note, to use `rows_patch` all columns in `df2` need to exist in `df1`, which is why I use `setdiff` to temporarily remove "v5".

**Output**

```
    v1  v2  v3   v4 v5
1  RDA COL ILL <NA> P3
2 OPCS  BR ILL <NA> P2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative, in case you are interested:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

dcast(
  merge(melt(df1,"v1"), melt(df2,"v1"), by=c("v1", "variable"),all = T)[!is.na(value.y), value.x:=value.y],
  v1~variable, value.var = "value.x"
)
```

Output:

```
       v1     v2     v3     v4     v5
   <char> <char> <char> <char> <char>
1:    OJK     BR    ILL     PE   <NA>
2:   OPCS     BR    ILL   <NA>     P2
3:    RDA    COL    ILL   <NA>     P3
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom function `multiple_replacer()`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

multiple_replacer <- function(x, y){
bind_rows(list(A = df1, B = df2), .id = 'id') %>%
  reframe(cur_data()[seq(nrow(df1)), ], .by = id) %>%
  group_split(id) %>%
  map(~ select(., -id)) %>% 
  set_names(c("mat1", "mat2")) %>%
  imap(function(df, name) assign(name, as.matrix(df), envir = .GlobalEnv)) %>%
  { mat1 <- get("mat1", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  mat2 <- get("mat2", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  mat1[is.na(mat1)] <- mat2[is.na(mat1)]
  as.data.frame(mat1)
  }
}

multiple_replacer(df1, df2)
```

```
    v1  v2  v3   v4   v5
1  RDA COL ILL <NA>   P3
2 OPCS  BR ILL <NA>   P2
3  OJK  BR ILL   PE <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `data.table`.

```
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[df2, on="v1", 
    `:=`(v2 = fcoalesce(v2, i.v2),
         v3 = fcoalesce(v3, i.v3),
         v5 = i.v5)]
```

**output**

```
       v1     v2     v3     v4     v5
1:    RDA    COL    ILL   <NA>     P3
2:   OPCS     BR    ILL   <NA>     P2
3:    OJK     BR    ILL     PE   <NA>
```